# How to set \tocauthor and \toctitle in LNCS style

Tags: table-of-contents, lncs

I have a paper accepted by an international conference that uses the LNCS format for publications.
For the preparation of the camera ready, they ask us to use the \tocauthor and \toctitle fields, as these are important to create the publication's Table of Contents.

how to add these fields knowing that I already have the \title and \author fields of the paper.

I appreciate any assistance

Comment: Before `\maketitle`:
(1) Short title for the TOC like
`\toctitle{Lecture Notes in Business Information Processing}`

(2) For `\tocauthor` use `~` between first name and name to avoid a break line inside author's names.
`\tocauthor{FistName~Lastname}`

Comment: yes, that's it, thank you very much